# Como introduzir polilinhas no google maps api v3 com datas guardadas na base de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

estou tentando mostrar no google maps api v3 polilinhas que estao guardadas na minha base de dados

Aqui esta a conexao com a base de dados conf.inc.php :

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','xxxx');
define('PASS','xxxxx');
define('DBSA','polilinha');
define('TABLE','marcador');

$link= mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DBSA) OR die('ERROR!');
?>
```

Obtenho os dados da minha base de dados desta maneira:

```
<?php require '_app/conf.inc.php';

//fazendo a consulta na base de dados`

$Qrcreate = "SELECT *  FROM " . TABLE. "";

$create   = mysqli_query($link,$Qrcreate);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($create)) {

vector[] = $row;

}
echo json_encode($vector);
?>
```

Meu output aparece desta maneira:

```
[{"id":"1","lat":"16.8875","lng":"-24.9893"},{"id":"2","lat":"16.8884","lng":"-24.9896"},{"id":"3","lat":"16.889","lng":"-24.9903"},{"id":"4","lat":"16.8891","lng":"-24.9911"}]
```

Meu problema e que nao sei como introduzir estes dados na varial (exemplo):

```
var flightPlanCoordinates =[
        {lat:16.88746121,  lng:-24.98925626},
        {lat:16.8883595,  lng:-24.98959154},]
```

Eu sei que preciso de fazer um loop mas nao sei como.
Ja vi post semelhantes mas nao consegui fazer, qualquer ajuda por favor .

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5389 ;-)

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao site. Se alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu seu problema, você pode [marcá-la como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Aqui não colocamos "RESOLVIDO" no título (ver o link acima).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que está utilizando javascript para realizar essa inserção de pontos na API , como linguagem PHP:

Neste caso eu estou somente imprimindo as  coordenadas, mas você pode usar essa iteração para inserir os pontos no mapa.

Na página de retorno onde você receberá o output do JSON Você fará assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pontos = <?php echo json_encode($vector) ?>;
    pontos = JSON.parse(pontos);
    $.each( pontos , function(chave, valor){
        console.log(valor['lat']);
        console.log(valor['lng']);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: E lembrando que você deve ter a bilbioteca jquery incluída no seu projeto.

Comment: obrigado cara funcionou, vou posta o codigo ai, valeu, lembrando que fiz com 3 arquivos 2 php e 1 html. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

lembrando que fiz em arquivos separados
Aqui esta a conexao com a base de dados, conf.inc.php :

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','xxxx');
define('PASS','xxxxx');
define('DBSA','polilinha');
define('TABLE','marcador');

$link= mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DBSA) OR die('ERROR!');
?>
```

Obtenho os dados da minha base de dados desta maneira,outputjson.php:

```
<?php require '_app/conf.inc.php';

//fazendo a consulta na base de dados`

$Qrcreate = "SELECT *  FROM " . TABLE. "";

$create   = mysqli_query($link,$Qrcreate);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($create)) {

vector[] = $row;

}
echo json_encode($vector);
?>
```

Meu output aparece desta maneira:

```
[{"id":"1","lat":"16.8875","lng":"-24.9893"},{"id":"2","lat":"16.8884","lng":"-24.9896"},{"id":"3","lat":"16.889","lng":"-24.9903"},{"id":"4","lat":"16.8891","lng":"-24.9911"}]
```

Arquivo html que contem o javascript e o google maps:

```
<?php
   require 'outpjson.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
       <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style >
    html, body { height: 100% ; margin: 0 ; padding: 0 ; }
    #map { height: 100% ; }
 </style>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>ExEMPLO INSERINDO POLILINHAS NO GOOGLE MAPS</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map"></div>

<script>
    function initMap(){
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

        center : {lat: 16.88627803, lng:-24.98922676 },
        zoom : 18,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

    var polilinha_data = <?php echo json_encode($vector) ?> ;

    // polilinha_data = JSON.parse(polilinha_data);
    var polylinePlanCoordinates =[];

    $.each(polilinha_data , function(chave , valor){
      polylinePlanCoordinates.push(  new google.maps.LatLng(valor['lat'], valor['lng']));

   });

    var path= new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: polylinePlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2

        });
   path.setMap(map);
}
</script>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key= INSERE A SUACHAVE API&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```